Subdiv on odd numbers instead of even numbers?
Is there an add-on or a way to incorporate the subdivision surface modifier to not split on base-2 (A quad is split into 4 quads on Level 1, 16 quads on Level 2, 64 quads on Level 3, etc.) and instead split on a variable base, like base-3 (so level 1 would split on quads into 9 quads) or base-5 (level 1 split into 25 quads)? It feels like it's something doable by the program, I just not sure how to do it.

Hello and welcome to BSE. If you are talking about making a modifier for that you would need to look into Geometry Nodes.  Unfortunately, replicating the Catmull-Clark subdivision algorithm purely with Geometry Nodes would be quite complex and likely not feasible due to the intricacies of the algorithm. Or do you mean just plain subdivision without catmull-clark? Or are you open to a python solution?

Maybe more like a subdivision without catmull-clark? Looking into C-C, it seems the reason it's base-2 is because it edge point equation divides by 4.  And I would be open to a python solution.

Why not directly use Right click > Subdivide in Edit Mode where you can set any number of cuts and even smoothness like catmull clark? Here's example using default cube https://snipboard.io/VgvNa8.jpg You can easily use it in your python workflows bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=2, smoothness=0.58) 
